# Is the auth token returned from the token provider, the same token as the system token?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

Trying to understand OAuth 2.0/OIDC in the context of an ASP.NET WebAPI server.

After B2C or other OIDC provider returns an IdP generated Token...do we use it directly -- or instead use it only as the source info for building a new *system* generated token, made up of custom claims (mostly coming from the claims returned from the IdP).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After B2C or other OIDC provider returns an IdP generated Token...do we use it directly -- or instead use it only as the source info for building a new system generated token, made up of custom claims (mostly coming from the claims returned from the IdP).

Yes, you can use the same Id_token or access token which is generated by B2C. You no need to create/ issue a new token if the B2C token satisfies your needs.